# Multiply numerical df with boolean df => result for False multiplication = np.nan instead of zero

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, product

When multiplying a numerical df with a boolean df, apparently True serves as 1 and False serves as 0. I want to set all values multiplied with False to np.nan so that they are different from the 0-values in the initial numerical df. NaN-values in the initial numerical df stay NaN-values of course.

**Desired output:**

```
   a    b    c
 NaN  0.0  3.0
 0.0  NaN  NaN
 9.0  NaN  NaN
 NaN  3.0  NaN
```

*Code:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [4,0,9,3],
                   "b": [0,7,np.nan,3],
                   "c": [3,7,np.nan,3]})

boolean = pd.DataFrame({"a": [False,True,True,False],
                        "b": [True,False,True,True],
                        "c": [True,False,False,False]})

output = df.mul(boolean)
print(output)
   a    b    c
 0.0  0.0  3.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 9.0  NaN  NaN
 0.0  3.0  0.0 => initial df zeros and zeros after boolean multiplication are mixed up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [4,0,9,3],
                   "b": [0,7,np.nan,3],
                   "c": [3,7,np.nan,3]})

boolean = pd.DataFrame({"a": [False,True,True,False],
                        "b": [True,False,True,True],
                        "c": [True,False,False,False]})

boolean[boolean==0]=np.nan

output = df.mul(boolean)
print(output)
```